# How to convert Mongo cli command to spring-data-mongo command for mongo aggreagtion using mongoTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb, mongo-shell, mongotemplate

I want to write the following query using mongo template.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      classes: {
        $map: {
          input: "$classes",
          as: "class",
          in: {
            classId: "$$class.classId",
            students: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$students",
                cond: { $in: ["$$this._id", "$$class.studentIds"] }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I have tried a lot but it is not working.

```
TypedAggregation<OrderDocument> aggregate = newAggregation(StudentDocument.class, 
                    match(Criteria.where("_id").is(id)),                    
                    project("classes")
                        .and(VariableOperators.Map
                                .itemsOf("classes")
                                .as("class")
                                .andApply(doc-> 
                                    new Document()
                                        .append("classId", "$$class.classId")                                       
                                        .append("students", ArrayOperators.Filter
                                                .filter("students")
                                                .as("student")           
 .by(ComparisonOperators.Eq.valueOf("$$student._id").equalToValue("$$class.studentIds"))))));
```

This is not giving the required response which is coming from the mongo shell command.

Comment: Have you found the answear?

Comment: No @big_OS . Yet I haven't found the answer